# fluentd-cloud-logging to parse GKE container log using glog

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

In our pod, the log output is using the glog utils. but fluentd-cloud-logging does not seem to understand the glog format, it ignores the tag from glog log line about the verbosity and severity, so when viewing those logs in cloud log viewer, they are in the wrong bucket.